# Deploying a Classification model Using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am working on creating a web app from my churn prediction analysis. There are 10 features, I want to base my prediction on. I am having issue printing out the prediction after I enter the values of the features.

The codes are below. Any help will be appreciated!

The Index.html file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Churn Prediction</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
  
  </head>
```

```
    <h1>Churn Prediction App</h1>
    <!-- <form id="prediction-form"> -->
    <!-- <form name="predictionForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="/predict"> -->

    <form action="{{ url_for('predict') }} method="POST"></form>
<!-- action="/predict" -->

  <label for="dependents">Dependents:</label>
  <select id="dependents" name="dependents">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <label for="tenure">Tenure (months):</label>
  <input type="number" id="tenure" name="tenure" required>
  <br>

  <label for="online-security">Online Security:</label>
  <select id="online-security" name="online_security">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No Internet Service</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <label for="online-backup">Online Backup:</label>
  <select id="online-backup" name="online_backup">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No Internet Service</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <label for="device-protection">Device Protection:</label>
  <select id="device-protection" name="device_protection">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No Internet Service</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <label for="tech-support">Tech Support:</label>
  <select id="tech-support" name="tech_support">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No Internet Service</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <label for="contract">Contract:</label>
  <select id="contract" name="contract">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="0">Month-to-month</option>
    <option value="1">One year</option>
    <option value="2">Two year</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <label for="paperless-billing">Paperless Billing:</label>
  <select id="paperless-billing" name="paperless_billing">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <label for="monthly-charges">Monthly Charges ($):</label>
  <input type="number" id="monthly-charges" name="monthly_charges" min="0" max="200" step="0.01" required>
  <br>

  <label for="total-charges">Total Charges ($):</label>
  <input type="number" id="total-charges" name="total_charges" step="0.01" required>
  <br>

  Class: {% if prediction [0]== 0 %}
  <h3>Not Likely to Churn</h3>
  
  {% endif %} <br>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    {% if prediction[0] == 1 %}
    <h3>Customer is likely to Churn</h3>
    
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Predict Churn">


  <!-- <input type="submit" value="Predict Churn"> -->

  <!-- <button type="submit" href="/">Predict Churn</button> -->
  <!-- value="Predict Churn"> -->
<!-- </form> -->
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
<!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
```

The app.py file code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle


app = Flask(__name__)

#load the model
model = pickle.load(open("xgb_tuned_hybrid.pkl", 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    prediction = ''
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())



@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST' ])
def predict():
    # Get the input values from the form
    dependents = int(request.form['dependents'])
    tenure = int(request.form['tenure'])
    online_security = int(request.form['online_security'])
    online_backup = int(request.form['online_backup'])
    device_protection = int(request.form['device_protection'])
    tech_support = int(request.form['tech_support'])
    contract = int(request.form['contract'])
    paperless_billing = int(request.form['paperless_billing'])
    monthly_charges = float(request.form['monthly_charges'])
    total_charges = float(request.form['total_charges'])






# Make a prediction with the model

prediction = model.predict([[dependents, tenure, online_security, online_backup, 
                                 device_protection, tech_support, contract, paperless_billing, 
                                  monthly_charges, total_charges]])
  
# Format the prediction result
result = "Yes, the customer is likely to churn" if prediction[0] == 1 else "No, the customer is less likely to churn"

# Return the prediction result to the HTML page
return render_template('index.html', prediction=result)
```

The web app picture:
[image]

Can anyone help me! What did do wrong!